# Show that the free group $F_n$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $F_k$ whenever 1≤k≤n.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

DEFINITIONS:

A word in $X ∪ X^{−1}$ is an ordered set of $n ∈ N ∪ {0}$ elements, each from $X ∪ X^{−1}$, with repetitions allowed. We write a word in the following way: $w = x_{\lambda_1}^{\epsilon_1} · · · x_{\lambda_n}^{\epsilon_n}$, where $i = ±1$. The number n is the length of the word.

Two words $u, v$ in $X ∪ X^{−1}$ are said to be adjacent if there exists words $w, w' \in X ∪ X^{−1}$ and $a ∈ X ∪ X^{−1}$
such that either (1) $u = ww'$ and $v = waa^{−1}w'$; or (2)
$v = ww'$ and $u = waa^{−1}w'$. If u, v are adjacent then we write $u ∼ v$.

Let $u, v$ be words in $X ∪ X^{−1}$. We say that $u, v$ are equivalent if there exists a finite sequence of words $w_1, · · · , w_n$ such that
$u = w_1 ∼ w_2 ∼ · · · ∼ w_n = v$. We denote equivalence of words by the notation $u ≈ v$.

We denote the equivalence class of a word $w$ by $[w]$.
Define $[u][v] = [uv]$.

A free group on the non-empty set $X$ is the set of equivalence classes of words in $X ∪ X^{−1}$.

We define the rank of $F(X)$ to be $|X|$.

---

I know that this is probably quite obvious, but I wanted to check/improve my reasoning.

A free group of rank $n$ is generated by $n$ elements. Therefore, since $k \le n$, we can generate a free group from $k$ of $F_n$'s generating elements.

Is this correct? How could I make it more rigorous if so?

Comment: Ultimately, the answer that works best for you will be one using facts about free groups you are most comfortable with. Are you defining free groups explicitly, or as a group with a particular universal property, or as a group satisfying a particular group presentation, or as the fundamental group of a rose, or ... something else?

Comment: I am defining free groups explicitly. I just feel like this isn't quite a proof. I am not even confident it is correct.

Comment: Tell me if this is right. Given a set $S = $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$, are you all defining the free group $F_n$ as the group of reduced words in $S$?

Comment: I have added a definition to the body.

Comment: What do you mean by "the set of equivalence classes"? You didn't define any equivalence relation.

Comment: I have added every definition relevant to free groups that I thought to be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct.

For a rigorous proof, it's enough to show that if $X\subseteq Y$, then $F(X)$ is a subgroup of $F(Y)$, which is quite immediate from the construction.